# findViewById returning null on LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, findviewbyid

I am programming an app which has many views, and then based on which view you click, it will update the views. When I try to find the layout to update the views, findViewById returns null. FYI: I am calling findViewById from a function that onCreate() calls. And yes, I am calling setContentView before calling that function.
MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updateViews();

}


public void updateViews(){
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
    layout.removeAllViews(); //NPE: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.LinearLayout.removeAllViews()' on a null object reference
}
```

What can I do to fix this issue? I suspect it has something to do with layout inflation, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'd bet money that in your layout XML file you don't have `android:id="@+id/list_layout"` in the LinearLayout tag.

Comment: I do. I have a <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> Those are only a few of the attributes, though.

Comment: The LinearLayout is the only thing that is inside the XML file.

Comment: and has id list_layout??

Comment: Yes, the layout does have list_layout.

Comment: post your xml file and also mention the name of the xml file.

Comment: The name of the XML file is activity_main.xml. It only contains the LinearLayout!

Comment: Why don't you post your XML? It is quite certain that something's wrong with it according to your description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I see only two reasons of `NPE` (Null Pointer Exception):

*First*. You don't have already `LinearLayout` with `R.id.list_layout` which is a really silly, because your project is making and it returns `NPE`.

You said that you have that view with this `android:id`. Let's say you have a `TextView` with this id. I swear that in that case Android Studio won't say about `NPE`, but about wrong view attributes like:

> Hey `rpurohit`! There's no TextView matched with this id. Check please correctness of your configuration.

*Second*. You said also that you have **only** one view, which is this `LinearLayout`. I can say only

> Congratulations! You've found an issue!

and explain you that you're trying to remove all views from your master `ViewGroup`, but like you said:

> The LinearLayout is the only thing that is inside the XML file.

so your IDE tries to remove any view from its parent, but as there's no `ChildViews`, it tells you about Null Pointer Exception.

I'm sure that now you understand your simple mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

> When you use  layout.removeAllViews(). that means remove all child
>   into the layout and dose not contain parent layout.

If you have this code:

```
  <Linearlayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </Linearlayout>
```

and call layout.removeAllViews() method. this remove textView and toggleButton but dose not remove parent layout(layout id).

> If you wantremove child and parent view . You can use like this:

```
 ((ViewGroup)layout.getParent()).removeAllViews();
```